# BigCommerce flyout menu (any hover activities on the site) not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bigcommerce

The category top menu has been working fine and all of a sudden it does not drop down for example when you hover over dresses it does not show further categories. The website is www.chicboutiquefashion.com
I have not edited the code for that are recently. The BC guys suggested that it could be a JS script preventing it from running. The only two JS scripts that have kicked in recently is the VeInteractive js and Google AdWords.
All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: your website has javascript errors, that can be the problem

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you point me to where I can see them?